# Will launchpad build my PPA projects one at a time in the order I send them?

Tags: package-management, compiling, ppa

I'm managing a large PPA with about 100 packages found in about 20 projects.

https://launchpad.net/~snapcpp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Whenever I want to rebuild a project, I send it and wait for it to be built, then send the next one.

There is a priority (a very specific order) for me to build each package since most packages depend on others. I have an SVG file that my build system generates showing me the priority (and changes pretty often these days):

[image]

What I'm wondering is whether I could send all the packages at once making sure that they get sent in the right order. Will launchpad build them one after the other? (i.e. if they were to decide to build them in parallel then it wouldn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

For sure, launchpad does not know anything about a build order or dependencies between packages within on launchpad project. You can only create a dependency between separate projects.

Instead, what I have worked on is a way to detect that a build is complete and the new packages available. This is a rather complicated process. Launchpad offers an API for the former. For the later, I had to implement my own curl call with a `HEAD` to see whether the file is available.

I have more info about that in this question: [How do I programmatically detect that my launchpad build process is done?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338731)